# How to get distances from all trained images in face recognition using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I was able to compile a simple face detection and recognition program in c# using EmguCV, following this article:

http://ahmedopeyemi.com/main/face-detection-and-recognition-in-c-using-emgucv-3-0-opencv-wrapper-part-1/

Once trained the recognizer, the Predict method correctly returns the corresponding Label (or distance) of the image passed.

Is it possible to get a list of all the distances between the image sample and the faces in the database?

Basically, I would have to write another predict method like suggested in:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/3494/adding-new-method-in-facerecognizer/

http://answers.opencv.org/question/19681/confidence-values-for-all-faces-from-facerecognizer/

But I'm working with c# and Emgu, how can I do?

Thanks for your help